# Adding a UIView/UIGestureRecognizer to the presented view in a UIPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to recreate the bottom drawer functionality seen in Maps or Siri Shortcuts by using a `UIPresentationController` by having it recognise user input and updating the `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` accordingly. However I want this mechanism to work independently of the presented `UIViewController` as much as possible so I'm trying to have the presentation controller add a handle area above the view. Ideally the view of the presented controller and the handle are should both recognise user input.

This works for the presented view, however any view I add to it responds to no `UIGestureRecognizer` at all. Am I missing something?

```
class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {

  private let handleArea: UIView = UIView()

  override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
    // Return some frame for now
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: 250, width: containerView!.frame.width, height: 500)
  }

  override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
    // Unwrap presented view
    guard let presentedView = self.presentedView else {
      return
    }

    // Set color
    self.handleArea.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    // Add to view hierachy
    presentedView.addSubview(self.handleArea)

    // Set constraints
    self.handleArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: presentedView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.handleArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: presentedView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.handleArea.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: presentedView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.handleArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56).isActive = true

    self.handleArea.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // These don't help
    self.handleArea.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    presentedView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    presentedView.bringSubviewToFront(self.handleArea)
  }

  override func presentationTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
    if completed {
      // Add gesture recognizer
      let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onHandleAreaTapped(sender:)))

      self.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
  }

  override func dismissalTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
    // Remove subview
    self.handleArea.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  // MARK: - Responder

  @objc private func onHandleAreaTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap") // No output
  }
}
```

[image: View debugger]

Comment: From this view debug hierarchy I can't recognize anything 

Comment: The blue controller presents the red one. The green view is the handle area added and constrained by the presentation controller. The click button simply triggers the transition. Or do you mean the perspective is odd?

Comment: I'm talking about perspective, yeah.

Comment: Hopefully this is better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by adding both the handle area and the view of the `presentedViewController` to a custom view and then overriding the `presentedView` property and returning my custom view.